# Ethereum private blockchain, Gas Limit

Tags: gas, private-blockchain

If I change the gaslimit in my genesis file does the network import the old blocks or only the new blocks? if it's yes how can I do it without modifying the genesis block ? I want to make the gaslimit higher without losting the old blocks

Answer (score 7):

Don't change the genesis file, as it changes the dynamics of the blockchain. Geth 1.4 (develop branch) has a `--targetgaslimit` flag that will cause the miner to converge towards a specific number opposed to the hard coded value. 1.4 RC1 should be released this week if you don't want to use `develop` itself.

Comment: Could you please explain why the dynamics of the blockchain changes with the gas limit? Is it because some previously valid transactions would become invalid with the gas change? Thx.

Comment: Every block has a gas limit that's contained within the block itself. This limit can only change with a certain amount between blocks (prev limit/1024 to be precise). If the change is larger, the block is not accepted any more.

Comment: Out of curiosity, assuming we're starting a new private network disregarding the old blocks. Would you still recommend starting from the default gasLimit and why (as opposed to setting say Uint64Max)?

Answer (score 5):

Edit 13/04/2016: `Péter Szilágyi` provided a reason not to change the gas limit in the genesis file:

> Every block has a gas limit that's contained within the block itself. This limit can only change with a certain amount between blocks (prev limit/1024 to be precise). If the change is larger, the block is not accepted any more.

---

I've just done some testing of your situation.

I get some strange results. Sometimes my blockchain is reset and mining starts again at block #1. Othertimes my blockchain is NOT reset and mining continues from where it was last at.

The is a `geth` command line parameter to import and export the blockchain data.

Export your current blockchain into a file using the `export` command:

```
geth {your other command line parameter options} export {filename}
```

Change your genesis file.

Import your exported blockchain back into the blockchain data directory using the `import` command:

```
geth {your other command line parameter options} import {filename}
```

If you want to be really sure that you don't reset your blockchain data, copy the whole data directory. In my case, when I start geth, I get the following information (I am using `--datadir ~/Test/data1`):

```
I0413 01:19:14.904877   23932 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/user/Test/data1/chaindata
I0413 01:19:14.914885   23932 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/user/Test/data1/dapp
```

Backup the whole `/home/user/Test/data1` subdirectory by copying the whole structure into a backup area. Run your `export` and `import` operations. If this is not successful, restore your data subdirectory by copying back the whole structure from your backed up data.