# Truffle: Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle

I am unsure why I keep getting this error:

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying Token...
  ... 0x02f042faec7c36c74bb0df346ccda5339ea653eb55c79996a3af81a9be055992
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

I am simply trying to deploy the standard ERC20 example from Consensys.

From what I understand this error occurs when a function is abstract, but I can't seem to find any of those, unless I get my definition of abstract wrong.

The ProToken contract inherits from Token one, which just follows ERC20 standards, what could be wrong ?

```
contract ProToken is Token {

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 constant MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]);
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        }
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }
}


contract Token {
    /// total amount of tokens
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_spender` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of tokens to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success);

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

Comment: I tried deploying your code in a testrpc network and it work as expected. A few thing to try: 1) Ensure the gas limit is at least 4700000 in your private network. 2) Update to a more recent version of truffle. 3) Remove or rename `build/` directory with the project artifacts to force truffle to start from scratch.

Comment: @Ismael Do you know how to set the gas limit to 4700000 in a private network?  I am having a similar issue and maybe I am setting it wrong?

Comment: @stone212 In geth you can modify your genesis.json file, but you will have to discard all existing blocks and start from an empty blockchain. Another option is to pass `--targetgaslimit <new_limit>` to geth, this will causes to slowly increase the block gas limit with each new mined block, the increment is small around 1/1000 of previous block, so it will take lots a block for a large increase. Parity has a similar option `--gas-floor-target`. See [Gas limit exceeded on private chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/gas-limit-exceeded-on-private-chain)

Comment: @stone212  This my provide a better explanation how gas can be configured in both geth and parity and the motivation behind [Accounts, Transactions, Gas, and Block Gas Limits in Ethereum](https://hudsonjameson.com/2017-06-27-accounts-transactions-gas-ethereum/)

Comment: @Ismael I have read that link so many times I think I might be able to recite it from memory.  But it is terrible as an explanation, so I am still in the same place I have been for months.  I keep trying things, but no one has definitive answers.  I start to think no one understands gas.

Comment: @stone212 I'd start learning geth first, it is the official ethereum client and there's plenity of tutorials to choose from. Pick a recent youtube tutorial about how to create a private network and start from there. If you know javascript you can use truffle+testrpc that allows to quickly create and test contracts without deploying a blockchain. Another option is remix.ethereum.org an online ide to deploy contract from a browser. All knowledge from geth is easily translatable to parity.

Comment: @Ismael geth isn't flexible enough for this private blockchain.  My private network is running very well, except of course that I can't find a clear explanantion of gas anywhere on the internet so I don't know if my settings are good or not.  Actually I probably know more than most of those YouTube channels do about private blockchains because I've been working on it for six months.  I do not know javascript.  The contract migrates with testrpc.

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same Issue, Downgrading Truffle worked for me fine.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g truffle
sudo npm install -g truffle@beta
```

For More Info on that subject try https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/660