# How does miners vote to determine the block gas limit?

Tags: gas-limit

In many posts people say "miners periodically vote to determine the block gas limit". But how actually do they vote and change the block limit? Do they vote for every block/or do it every day or for some other fixed period of time? Another related question: on September 2019 there was a jump of gas limit (8M to 10M). How did that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/59673/33305) from another user fits perfectly. To quote:

> strategy: gasLimit of block-to-mine is set based on parent's gasUsed
>   value.  if parentGasUsed > parentGasLimit * (2/3) then we increase it,
>   otherwise lower it (or leave it unchanged if it's right at that usage)
>   the amount increased/decreased depends on how far away from
>   parentGasLimit * (2/3) parentGasUsed is.

The targetGasLimit parameter is now deprecated and miners can use `--miner.gastarget value` to set their own gas limit. The default in geth is 8,000,000.